# Count all rows in database where column equals to `YES`

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database `crm_data` in which I have multiple tables. Now I want to calculate all rows in whole database where `column_name` value is equal to `YES`. To calculate all rows in database I am using this mysql query.

My SQL Query:

```
$sql = $db_con2->prepare("SELECT SUM(TABLE_ROWS) AS all_rows FROM 
       INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'crm_data'");
$sql->execute();
$all_rows = $sql->fetchAll();
if (count($all_rows) > 0) {
   foreach ($all_rows as $all_rows) {
      echo $all_rows['all_rows'];
   }
} else {
   $all_rows = '0';
}
```

Thanks

Comment: And.. what's the issue?

Comment: It is giving me all rows sum without any condition but I need sum of all rows where `column_name` value is equal to `YES`.

Comment: So you have the same column, representing the same thing, in multiple tables?

Comment: @PatrickQ yes you are right

Comment: I'm not sure the above query is doing what you think it is doing, it is just giving you a count of all rows within your database crm_data database at the moment.

Comment: @Jackhardcastle yes you got it but now I want just those rows where `column_name` value is `YES`

Comment: There's a good chance that you should reconsider a database redesign then.  It's hard to say without seeing your schema, but generally, having the same info in multiple tables is not ideal. That being said, you're probably going to have to fetch a list of all your table names, loop through that list, and then get a count from each table individually.

Comment: I know that if I will go through single table it will be easy but the product required multiple tables in which every table represent a company. In which we have all company info separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did I went back to basics and used `SHOW TABLES` then I use table query `SELECT * FROM $company WHERE rental_status = 'YES'`. and I got the results.

BTW thanks guys giving me your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i hope it works for you

```
// connect to Database.
   $links = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name );

   if($links === false){
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
      }

//get total
    $n = 'YES';



$result = mysqli_query($links,"SELECT   Count(*) As column_name FROM crm_data WHERE column_name='".$n."'");

                                                       $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);



                                                if($rows){

                                                    $gt = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

                                                     $total = $gt["column_name"];

                                                    }
                                   echo $total;
```

Using PDO as requested.

```
 // using PDO
  $servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //echo "Connected successfully"; 

// call for the row count here.

$w='YES';
$rs = $conn->prepare("SELECT   Count(*) As column_name FROM crm_data WHERE column_name='".$w."'");
$rs->execute();
$count = $rs->rowCount();
echo '<p>Total:'.$count.'</p>';
}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: convert mysqli to PDO , but  the code will give you what you want

Comment: Thanks but still you are making mistake like `YES` is a column value not column name and I need is show column name `X` WHERE value is `YES`.

Comment: `WHERE column_name='".$w."` and the value of `$w="YES"` so the column_name has a value of YES as requested.

Answer (score -2):

You're not querying the data in your database you're now querying the actual structure of the database, which is concerning.

Nevertheless...

```
 SELECT SUM(`COLUMN_NAME`) FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` where `COLUMN_NAME` = 'YES' AND `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'crm_data';
```

Is the query you are looking for...

Comment: it will throw unknown column error because I already tried this.